# Sorting from multiple tables using single query

Tags: mysql, sorting

I have multiple tables in my database(say 5), each table having a row `date`(datetime). Is it possible to show some(say 8) records form these tables with the most recent date.
For single table I use the query,

`SELECT * FROM tbl_name ORDER BY date DESC`

Is it possible to achieve this but from multiple tables using a single query?

Comment: Look into `UNION` queries

Answer (score 0):

You can combine multiple `select` queries with `UNION` but the columns must be of the same type and number.

```
SELECT a, date FROM tbl1
UNION 
SELECT a, date FROM tbl2
ORDER by date
```

but you cannot have more or less columns and they cannot be of another type.

Comment: I added parens so that the ORDER BY would be fore the UNION, no the last SELECT.